# Installing docker on VM during installation via vagrantfile

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker, vagrant

I am trying to have Docker installed as part of setup of a VM via vagrant.
I have added to the vagrant file the following:

```
  # Install Docker: 
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "./shared_directory/install_scripts/install_docker.sh"
```

with `install_docker.sh` being:

```
echo "-------Try to install docker---------"

cd ~
sudo su -

apt-get update
apt-get install apt-transport-https  ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
echo "Y" | apt-get install docker-ce
```

Using the instructions provided [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).
It should be noted that when I use create this VM (regardless of whether I call my `install_docker.sh` ), if I use these commands inside the VM (e.g. by copying and pasting them from the shell file), Docker is successfully installed.

When I am trying to do that using Vagrantfile and the shell script (via `vagrant up`), I'm getting the following:

`default: -------Try to install docker---------
    default: Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
    default: Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease
    default: Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
    default: Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
    default: Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
    default: Reading package lists...
    default: Reading package lists...
    default: Building dependency tree...
    default: Reading state information...
    default: apt-transport-https is already the newest version (1.2.26).
    default: ca-certificates is already the newest version (20170717~16.04.1).
    default: curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.7).
    default: software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.20.7).
    default: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    default: OK
    default: pub   4096R/0EBFCD88 2017-02-22
    default:       Key fingerprint = 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
    default: uid                  Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
    default: sub   4096R/F273FCD8 2017-02-22
    default: Reading package lists...
    default: Building dependency tree...
    default: Reading state information...
    default: Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
    default: This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
    default: is only available from another source
    default: E
    default: :
    default: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate`

What should I do to ensure that Docker is installed when setting-up the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you should also `apt-get update` after adding the repository (last 2 lines of your script).

> #### Install Docker CE
>
> 1. Update the apt package index.
>
>    ```
>     $ sudo apt-get update
>    ```
> 2. Install the latest version of Docker CE (...)
>
>    ```
>     $ sudo apt-get install docker-ce
>    ```

So, you could try changing last lines of your script to:

```
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
apt-get update
echo "Y" | apt-get install docker-ce
```

You could also try changing last line to:

```
apt-get -y install docker-ce
```

Although I don't know if it'll make any difference.

If all fails, there's a script available down that page in "**Install using the convenience script**" section, unless you can't/don't want to use it.

Comment: It seems that my problem was not including  `sudo apt-get update` a second time. 
Replacing `echo "Y" | apt-get install docker-ce` with `apt-get -y install docker-ce` was, as you suggested, not necessary.

Comment: I got: `E: Unable to locate package docker-ce`

Comment: @Snowcrash add docker's repository first! Details are in OP's 2nd code snippet and link to their official documentation is just underneath. See these [detailed instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

Comment: The `convenience script` fails with: ```sh get-docker.sh
# Executing docker install script, commit: 36b78b2
+ sh -c echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010```

Comment: @Snowcrash did you follow the instructions under link provided? You need to add Docker’s official GPG key. It's described in detail [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository). If everything you followed there fails, i think you should ask a new question on StackExchange at this point.